# SSRS Timeout preference?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I had a scenario where I need to fetch large amount of data from a stored procedure and bind it to a table. Since I got timeout, I set time out for the **shared dataset** at 
Shared Data Source properties->Edit(Connection string)->Advanced->Connect Timeout

Also I set time out for **Dataset** at
Dataset Properties->Query->Timeout

So the question is while the proc gets executed which Timeout will be considered? Is there any order like one time out should be higher than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the query is executed it will always be the query/dataset time out that will considered during execution of the query.

To Summarize

### A )Case when using SSRS on report server

1.Set Query DataSet timeout to max
2. Go to Report server if you are the admin
   Click on report ->Manage ->Processing option ->In the Report Timeout --- 
   ->Select "Do not Timeout"

### B)Case when running SSRS in ASP.Net as rdlc file in web.config add the following entry under

```
     <system.web>
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxUrlLength="10999" 
       maxQueryStringLength="2097151"  executionTimeout="3600"/> 
       </system.web>
```

### C) SQL Server Settings(applicaable to case  A and B)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Regardless of how you are running the SSRS reports
Make sure that in your SQL server settings too, the Execution time out is set to 0 , which is max.

Go to Connect Database in SSMS, Select the database and click options
In the connection Section select "Execution TimeOut = 0"

Comment: I think part of your answer is missing.. could you help by completing it? Also by meaning query timeout...are you refering to dataset timeout?

Comment: yes , query timeout means dataset timeout in SSRS. Also I have updated the answer and made it more concise and easy to understand .Hope that helps.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include web.config .I did add the tag for web.config before too, for some odd reason it was hiding in the view .Seems like a bug in the portal :)

Comment: Thanks for the help..i got more info then expected for